# Why do Reggie Ledoux and Errol call Rust "little priest"?

Tags: true-detective

I found an interesting [question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueDetective/comments/2052tx/spoiler_why_did_ledoux_and_errol_call_rust_priest/) about Reggie Ledoux and Errol repeatedly calling Rust a "priest" in *True Detective* season 1:

> In the behind-the-scenes feature for Episode #5, Ledoux is seen telling Rust that he's "a priest too." Then, when Rust is walking through the catacombs in Episode #8, Errol refers to him as "little priest."

Why do they do this and what does it mean?

Comment: Hold on, did you just [copy this question from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueDetective/comments/2052tx/spoiler_why_did_ledoux_and_errol_call_rust_priest/)? That's plagiarism.

Comment: In the future, if you copy something verbatim from another website, please put it into proper quote blocks and include the source you took it from (preferrably with a link thereto).

Answer (score 1):

[As theorized on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueDetective/comments/20dhzj/why_did_errol_call_rust_little_priest/):

> Because to the cultists, death means ascension to another dimension.
>   The Infernal Plane. Escaping the loop of time.
>
> To kill them for their sacrifices was a blessing. Errol says as much
>   to Cohle as he makes his way through the maze:
>
> > "You blessed Reggie ... Dewall"
>
> He knew that Cohle was there to kill him. So from his perspective,
>   Cohle was like a priest bestowing a blessing.

But that thread has other possible explanations. [Another one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueDetective/comments/206uq2/a_theory_on_little_priest_rust_as_disciple_of_void/cg0hie9) links this to Rust's ability to extract confessions.

Comment: For the first theory it can't be correct because Rust didn't kill anybody yet when Reggie told him that. For the second part how could Reggie and Errol knew that Rust was good at getting confessions from people ?!